# How can I calculate log?

Tags: algorithms, education

$$
-0.4 \cdot \log(0.4) - 0.3 \cdot \log(0.3) - 0.3 \cdot \log(0.3) = 1.571
$$

The answer is given. How can I calculate the equation for obtaining $1.571$? Please help me understand.

Comment: Calculate how? on a calculator?

Comment: @DennisGulko: I think something is wrong at the OP's identity. ??!

Comment: The question is what do you mean when you write $\log$. Do you mean $\log_{10}$, $\log_e$ or $\log_2$ (the last seems to be the correct, according to WA)

Comment: They're base-2 logarithms.  Otherwise the answer is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As Michel pointed out, this equation is only correct if you're using base-2 logs. Writing $\lg x$ for $\log_2 x$ the left side of your equation is
$$
\begin{align}
-0.4\lg(0.4)-0.6\lg(0.3) &= -0.4\lg(4/10)-0.6\lg(3/10)\\
 &=-0.4(\lg4-\lg10)-0.6(\lg3-\lg10)\\
 &=-0.4\lg4+0.4\lg10-0.6\lg3+0.6\lg10\\
 &= -0.4(2)-0.6\lg3+\lg10\\
 &=-0.8-0.6\lg3+\lg(2\cdot5)\\
 &=-0.8-0.6\lg3+\lg2+\lg 5\\
 &=-0.2-0.6\lg3+\lg5 \\
&\approx 1.571
\end{align} 
$$